# my href is not redirecting to /logout page

Tags: java, yui, osgi, freemarker

I'm facing a trouble with my href which is listed inside yui menu. Here is my code

```
<a class="yuimenuitemlabel" href= "<@spring.url "/logout"/>"          />
```

For some reason this link is not redirecting to /logout.
PTW, when I write /logout manually in my URL, it works fine. It is that the href tag is not putting /logout in the URL.
Any suggestions?

Comment: go to your page and check sources/by firebug what you really have in href

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `HREF` tag doesn't seem to have a text. Further, you might want to try wrapping the freemarker tag with single quotes. Try this:-

```
<a class="yuimenuitemlabel" href='<@spring.url "/logout"/>'>Logout</a>
```